# Using ParsleyJS within Backbone

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js, parsley.js

What is the correct approach to using Parsley within a Backbone app when taking an Unobtrusive approach?

I can successfully get Parsley validation to trigger on submit with an attribute based approach, but when I setup the validation programmatically in the initialize method, which you can see here,

https://github.com/aedenj/blog-examples/blob/master/parsleyjs/app/index.js.coffee

I get nothin!

Thank you for your time.